# AIMP: how to repeat the playlist?

Tags: aimp

In AIMP v4.13 (build 1893) there is a button to **toggle track repeat**: [image: Repeat track toggle]

How do you make it **repeat the current playlist**, not only the track?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'd like to add that there's a shortcut for this: just right-click on this icon and choose **Repeat playlist** in the context menu.

Comment: Goddammit I've searched the whole aimp UI and settings in and out but I never would've looked there! Thank you very much!
But seriously, they could've hidden a dead body there and noone would find it

Comment: @timetowonder, You are welcome! I found it by accident, my hand slipped when I right-clicked the player for some other settings.

Answer (score 6):

Menu > Preferences > Player > Automatic:

On end of playlist: **repeat playlist**.

Answer (score -1):

Menu > Preferences > Player > Automatic

See how to repeat the playlist in AIMP:

[image: Repeat the playlist in AIMP]